# Is entropy maximized for steadily driven systems?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, non-equilibrium

Suppose we send an electric current through a piece of metal. If we knew only the average energy and current through the sample, it would seem natural to assume the state of the sample is described by a probability distribution (or density matrix) with the most entropy for the given current and energy. The density matrix of the system, satisfying such maximum entropy condition, can be shown to be equal to
$$
\hat{\rho}=\frac{1}{Z}e^{-\beta \hat{H}-\alpha \hat{I}},\quad (1)
$$
where $\hat{H}$ is the Hamiltonian of the system, $\hat{I}$ is the current, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are coefficients to fix the mean energy and current.

Now, even though it may appear natural (at least to me) to pick the probability distribution as containing the least amount of information (i.e. the most entropy) for the given macroscopic variables, I do not see any other physical reasons to make such choice. We know that a piece of metal cannot have a constant current without generating heat, so something needs to take the heat away, which would make the state of the system depend on the model of the thermostat. In other words, it appears to be impossible to have a model-less steady distribution of the type (1).

Still, the concept of maximum entropy in steadily excited state looks extremely appealing, and I wonder if distributions of the type (1) have any physical significance?

Comment: Can you ellaborate on were (1) comes from?

Comment: Yes, of course. You try to maximize etropy keeping other quantitites constant, which translates into finding an extremum of $A=\langle\ln{\hat{\rho}}\rangle+\alpha(\langle I\rangle-I_0)+\beta(\langle E\rangle-E_0)+\gamma (\langle 1\rangle-1)$ over density matrix $\hat{\rho}$. You assume form (1) and try to demonstrate that $\delta A=O(\rho^2)$. You can do the full thing (working in the basis $\beta \hat{H}+\alpha \hat{I}$, or you can notice similarities between this and regular entropy maximization  and make a shortcut.

Comment: Corrections. **you try to maximize entropy while keeping other quantities constant.

**$\delta A= O(\delta \hat{\rho}^2)$